# Difference between outer and inner path length for a constant-width Path around a Closed Loop

Tags: geometry

If there's a path of constant width $w$ that forms an arbitrary closed, non self-intersecting loop, what will be the difference between the length of the inner and outer edge of the path. That is, if person A were to run on the inside of this path around the loop, and person B were to run on the outside of the path, how much more distance would person B run?

My intuition tells me the answer is $2 \pi w$, but I don't know how I would prove it. Also, if the answer relies on other numbers, please assign them as necessary.

Note: a constant-width path can be imagined as having been drawn by a single, continuous paint brush stroke. (this means that a loop that is a square is impossible)

Comment: That's a funny result, after looking into it a little I came to the same answer as you. I think I have a very non-rigorous proof of it, so I'll wait for someone to post a rigorous one (if you're in a hurry, I could give you my version though).

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't in a hurry, but thanks for offering :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your hangup is the definition of "width." If it's the distance from any point on either path edge to the closest point on the other edge, your problem with square paths goes away, for one thing. The outer edge goes becomes a 90 deg section of a circle at the corners, and the difference in paths is $2\pi w$. That can be generalized, obviously, to rectangles, and to, not quite so obviously, any polygon. At each corner, concave or convex, one of the edges has a rounded section and the twists and turns for each edge add up to 360 degrees around the loop. A curved loop is a polygon with infinitesimal sides and lots of corners. I don't know what you need for a proof, as such, but I hope my next-step helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think toiler's proof on polygons generalize to all the paths you described, by using some convergence argument. Below is a more analytical take.

Consider some closed, non-intersecting, $0$-width path $\gamma$. If a person walks on $\gamma$ by holding its arm horizontally, in the normal direction, we end up with a path of width $2\times$arm length $=w$. To make this a valid constant width path, the hands of the person should never pass over the same point more than once (1), and the normal direction should be continuous over the whole path (2).
If you have the arc-length parameterization $\gamma(s)$ of your path, (2) holds if $\gamma'$ is defined and continuous. For (1), a sufficient (but maybe not necessary, no clue about that) condition is that the radius of curvature of $\gamma$ is everywhere greater than $w/2$. Curvature is defined if $\gamma''$ is.

Assume that $\gamma$ satisfies the above properties. You can approximate your path $\gamma$ everywhere by its osculating circles, so you move everywhere on small circular arcs. Denote the angular width on these arcs by $\lvert d\theta\rvert$.
When you move forwards a small distance, one hand moves forwards by $(r-w/2)\lvert d\theta\rvert$ and the other by
$(r+w/2)\lvert d\theta\rvert$. If we take $d\theta >0$ when the outer hand
moves forward by $(r+w/2)\lvert d\theta\rvert$, then
$d\theta <0$ when the outer hand moves forward by $(r-w/2)\lvert d\theta\rvert$.
In every case, we end up with a path length difference of $w\,d\theta$.

Now because we assumed that $\gamma$ is closed without self-intersection,
$\int_\gamma d\theta=2\pi$. So the total path length difference is $2\pi w$.

Answer (score 0):

Your result correct due to Pappu's swept area theorem when generalized to varying curvature. It can be also proved by Gauss- Bonnet theorem.